# Autocomplete function call with parameters in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Is it possible to make pycharm autocomplete insert also all the named parameters that a function has and not just the function name? So when code completion triggers and I see my suggested function, I also see the list of arguments the function expects. Can pycharm add the expected arguments inside my code completion?

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl + space when cursor is in the brackets:

[image: image1]

When the cursor is in between the brackets after autocomplete:

[image: image2]

Comment: Right, but those are randomly sorted. Is there a way to say, "show me only variables"?